# Dependable categories

Tags: php

my problem is that i need to make dependable categories with php but i want them to take their options from txt files any ideas how i can do both? 
The idea is that they choose one category at first drop down menu and then choose one category at second but i want the categories to be able to change with txt files..
any advice is really apreciated! 
Thx for your time!
this is an idea of what i made

```
<tr>
        <td height="67" align="right">ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑ</td>
        <td><label>
          <select name="ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑ" id="ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑ" class="update" >
            <option value="ΚΟΙΝΟΧΡΗΣΤΑ" selected="selected">ΚΟΙΝΟΧΡΗΣΤΑ</option>
            <option value="ΘΕΡΜΑΝΣΗ">ΘΕΡΜΑΝΣΗ</option>
            <option value="ΑΝΕΛΚΥΣΤΗΡΑΣ">ΑΝΕΛΚΥΣΤΗΡΑΣ</option>
            <option value="ΕΙΔΙΚΕΣΔΑΠΑΝΕΣ">ΕΙΔΙΚΕΣ ΔΑΠΑΝΕΣ</option>
            <option value="ΙΔΙΟΚΤΗΤΩΝ">ΙΔΙΟΚΤΗΤΩΝ</option>
            </select>
          <select name="ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑ2" id="ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑ2" class="update" disabled="disabled">
            <option value="ΘΥΡΩΡΟΣ" selected="selected">ΘΥΡΩΡΟΣ</option>
            <option value="ΕΙΔΗΚΑΘΑΡΙΟΤΗΤΑΣ" selected="selected">ΕΙΔΗ ΚΑΘΑΡΙΟΤΗΤΑΣ</option>
          </select>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Dependent (or hierarchical), not dependable.

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: how many levels do you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: The code is commented enough to be self explaining

```
<?php 
$list1 = file("/path/to/options1.txt");/// read the first options list file

$selectedOption = $list1[0]; // default selected value is the first option as written in the code snipet above

if( isset($_GET["option1"]) && !empty( $_GET["option1"] ) ) {
    $selectedOption = urldecode( $_GET["option1"] ) ; // if the user changed the selection we update the second list
}

$list2 = file("/path/to/{$selectedOption}.txt");/// read the second options file based on the first element in the first list (since it will be the default selected value)

$currentUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
        location.href = "<?php echo "$currentUrl";?>" + "?option1=" + document.getElementById("option1").value ;
    }
</script>

<tr>
        <td height="67" align="right">ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑ</td>
        <td><label>
          <select name="option1" id="option1" class="update" onchange="javascript:load()" >
            <?php
            foreach( $list1 as $_ ){
                $selected = "";
                if( trim( $selectedOption == trim( $_ ) ) )
                    $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
                echo "<option value=\"". urlencode( $_ ) ."\" $selected >$_</option>\n";
            }
        ?>
        </select>

      <select name="option2" id="option2" class="update">
        <?php
            $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
            foreach( $list2 as $_ ){
                echo "<option value=\"". urlencode( $_ ) ."\" $selected >$_</option>\n";
                $selected = ""; // only the first element will be marked as selected
            }
        ?>
      </select>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Warning: file(koinoxrhsta .txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\Douleia\Dependend-categories.php on line 8 i cant figure out why its not working? the first txt works perfect...

Comment: check the file name, as I see there is a space between `koinoxrhsta` and `.txt` is that normal ?

Comment: file("/path/to/{$selectedOption}.txt") it has no spaces... if i write it like this   file("$selectedOption.txt") it works but for 1 time only then i get same error and its not holding the first option.. for example if i click option 2 it will show in second category the options but at first category it will to back to option 1

Comment: the warning message shows that you have an additional space perhaps this what causes your issue, try to use `file( trim($selectedOption).".txt")`   the `trim` function removes any additional spaces in your variable, so this may work for you

Comment: OK it worked but if i change my mind and try to choose something else it shows same error. and its not holding at the first category the option i clicked. any ideas?? Really thx my friend i couldnt do it without you!!

Comment: you are very welcome, and if it helped you, don't forget to accept :) , but I didn't really get what you told me the last, can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: ok for example i click option 2 on first list and option 3 on second but then i want to change first list option if i click option 4 at list1 i get same error Warning: : failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\Douleia\Dependend-categories.php on line 8 and another thing is that i want on list 1 to hold my choise. thx!

Comment: and can you explain me this line $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27558/discussion-between-abu-romaissae-and-ant-mar)

Comment: I'm waiting in the chat room that we can discuss better

Comment: its still not holding what i choose and if i choose another option i get error

Comment: can you come to chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27558/discussion-between-abu-romaissae-and-ant-mar

Comment: can you send me a way to contact you plz?

Comment: really cant find your email.. my email is antonis_martalis@hotmail.com thx!

Comment: I've sent you an email, didn't you get it ?